# Embed Image into video - FFMPEG or JW player?

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg, jwplayer, embedding

So I thought to embed the image as part of video content while converting the m4a to mp4. The output file has the image as video content and it plays as expected in VLC but when the same was streamed from my CDN using JW player, I do not see the image as video content, still it is black and audio is heard. Not sure what is the issue with embeding. I used the FFMPEG to embed image as video content.

On the other hand is there any posibility with JW player to overlay an image as video content while audio can be heard in back end?

Answer (score 1):

You need
[to loop](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images)
the image

```sh
ffmpeg -loop 1 -r 1 -i img.png -i audio.m4a -shortest -filter:v \
  'crop=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2' out.mp4
```

- repeat image over and over
- once per second
- stop video when audio stops
- cut image to even dimensions if necessary